# Audio.js audio player how to stop downloading audio file when started

Tags: html5-audio

I am using this [audio plugin](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) for my website. Has anyone experience with this plugin? If you visit that page you will see demo audio player. You will see that audio player starts downloading audio file immediately. How can prevent immediate downloading feature of audio player? So it should start downloading when I press play and stop downloading when I press stop. This feature I need for traffic economy. For example if I want to listen I start playing, further if I will not like it, I want to stop it playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent an `<audio>` element from downloading on page load just set the `preload` attribute to `"none"`. As for stopping the download after it has begun, you should be able to do that by simply removing the `<audio>` element from the page. The plugin you mentioned may also require you to run an additional command to clean up anything it added to the page.